# Get key code / click / which triggered change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

is it possible to find out from (jquery) change event handler what triggered the change event - keypress of which key or mouse click?

My use case: I have dynamic list of input[type=text] items, if user fills last empty item I add new input[type=text] for another item. I want to auto-focus it if user pressed tab (which triggered the change event), but not for example when user clicked somewhere (so the change is aslo triggered, but user may want to focus something else).

Simplified example:

https://jsfiddle.net/yxu82p1o/1/

```
<input type=text>
<script>
function addMore() {
  $('input').off('change.addMore');
  $('<input type=text>').insertAfter($('input').last()).on('change.addMore', addMore);
}
$('input').on('change.addMore', addMore);
</script>
```

PS. I can figure out workarounds like attaching another keyup event and figuring out pressed key from it, but it would be much simpler and cleaner to find out from change event what caused it.

Comment: add `e` to the addMore arguments: `addMore(e)`, then check `e.which` for keyboard or `e.button` for mouse

Comment: @bozdoz - `e.which` and `e.button` will be `undefined` on `change`, at least in chrome, or am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an option. Listen for the `keydown` event on the `input` elements and if the TAB key triggered the event and the element is an `input` element trigger the `change` event on the `input` element. Then focus the dynamically added `input` element.

```js
function addMore() {
  $('input').off('change.addMore');
  $('<input type=text>').insertAfter($('input').last()).on('change.addMore', addMore);
}
$('input').on('change.addMore', addMore);

$('body').on('keydown', 'input', function(e){
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  if (keyCode == 9 && this.tagName === "INPUT") {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).change();
    $(':text').last().focus();
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is quite simple workaround, but still a workaround - I will accept it if noone comes with direct answer if I can determine cause of change event ;)

Comment: Sure, no problem. I am not aware of a way to get `keyCode` information from a `change` event being triggered when an input element of type "text" loses focus, but maybe someone else has a better idea. It would be nice to have though. ;)